# Thread-first array map literal to anonymous function in Clojure

Tags: clojure

Quite perplexed — if

`(#(get % "a") {"a" "b"})`

returns `"b"`, why doesn’t

`(-> {"a" "b"} #(get % "a"))`

also return `"b"`?

(The second errors w/ `CompilerException java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap cannot be cast to clojure.lang.ISeq`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thread first macro **always places the arguments as the second item in the list**. So in this case it is inserting it into the anonymous function definition instead of into a call to the anonymous function

```
(-> {"a" "b"} #(get % "a"))
```

expands into*:

```
#(get {"a" "b"} % "a")
```

which simply returns an anonymous function without running it. If you add another set of `()` it should work.

```
(-> {"a" "b"} (#(get % "a")))
```

will expand to:

```
(#(get % "a") {"a" "b"})
```

which places the arguments after the anonymous function in the outer list.

*I have expanded this by hand to show the idea more clearly. This is not the literal expansion (whch expands the reader macro and adds namespaces.

Comment: In fact, `(-> {"a" "b"} #(get % "a"))` would be expanded to something like `(fn* {"a" "b"} [p1__660#] (get p1__660# "a"))` because #() is transformed to fn form at read time, i.e. before macro expansion.

Comment: This is what I refer to as "whch expands the reader macro" in the last sentence.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the sentence.